# NotSupportedException when trying to parse plist document

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, windows-phone

I'm currently working on a Windows Phone 7 Application for the company I work for. For the configuration part I'd like to share the configuration that is used for our iPhone Application and stored on a remote server in a plist file.

I use `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` to `Parse` a string I downloaded using a WebClient instance.

This is the code:

```
        Uri plistLocation = new 
            Uri(@"http://iphonevnreporter.vol.at/Settings.bundle/mw_test.plist");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += ((sender,e) => {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

                    //XElement element = XElement.Parse(e.Result.ToString());
                    var dictItems = xdoc.Descendants("dict");
                    foreach (XElement elem in dictItems)
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        client.DownloadStringAsync(plistLocation);
```

In this example the plist is just having a `dict` Element under the root `plist` element and nevertheless I am receiving the `NotSupportedException`. The Exception occurs at `XDocument.Parse(e.Result)`.

This is the StackTrace:

```
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration..ctor(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)
   at VorarlbergOnline.MainViewModel.<FillSections>b__10(
                 Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted
            (DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs     e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext 
        executionContext,     ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Loading other XML files works fine, so the code seems to be ok. I checked if the referenced dtd could be the problem, but it loads fine. So I'm kind of out of ideas now.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? We can't tell. It's also not at all clear why you have an empty catch block - never a good idea. Also, is there any more information in the message than just `NotSupportedException`?

Comment: As I said the exception is thrown by `XDocument.Parse(e.Result);`. I haven't implemented error handling yet, therefore the empty Exception. The thrown Exception has just "NotSupportedException" as its Message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, now I've actually looked at the file in the raw rather than via a browser, I'm sure this is the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
          "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

It looks like doctype parsing just isn't supported in Windows Phone 7. You could do a quick and dirty hack to remove it though:

```
string xml = e.Result;
int docTypeIndex = xml.IndexOf("<!DOCTYPE");
if (docTypeIndex != -1)
{
    int docTypeEnd = xml.IndexOf(">", docTypeIndex);
    // TODO: Decide what to do if docTypeEnd is -1...
    xml = xml.Substring(0, docTypeIndex) + xml.Substring(docTypeEnd + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect the doctype definition to be a problem! Normally I only had issues when the URL 404'd.

Answer (score 4):

The problem really is the DOCTYPE, that cannot be parsed by `XDocument` on Windows Phone. A shorter solution would be using Regex to remove the DOCTYPE reference:

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(e.Result, "<!DOCTYPE.+?>", string.Empty);
XDocument.Parse(replaced);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I like the regular expression approach.